# Vue.js Nuxt - cannot access Array (value evaluated upon first expanding error)

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have the following function which gives me an array called `URLs`

```
        const storageRef = this.$fire.storage.ref().child(fileName)
        try {
            const snapshot = storageRef.put(element).then((snapshot) => {
                snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
                    urls.push(url)
                })
            })
            console.log('File uploaded.')
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e.message)
        }
    });
    console.log(urls)
    console.log("about to run enter time with imageurls length " + urls.length)
```

When I run `console.log(URLs)` initially I do see the array like the following

```
[]
0: "testvalue"
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

However, there is a small information icon stating

```
This value was evaluated upon first expanding. The value may have changed since.
```

Because of this, when I try to get the length of `URLs`, I get zero, meaning the value is being updated.

Does anyone know what's happening? I am using Vue.JS/Nuxt.